# Error: not found: java Usage: selenium-standalone action [options]

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

trying to install selenium-standalone but getting this error, any idea?

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install

not found: java
Usage: selenium-standalone action [options]
```

I have java installed but don't know if it needs to be in a specific file location.

```
Bootcamp Student 2@DESKTOP-AI3C36U MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Webdriverframework
$ npm install -save-dev selenium-standalone@6.15.3                                                                      npm WARN webdriverframework@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ selenium-standalone@6.15.3
added 18 packages from 18 contributors and audited 493 packages in 6.873s
found 0 vulnerabilities


Bootcamp Student 2@DESKTOP-AI3C36U MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Webdriverframework
$ ./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install                                                                       not found: java
Usage: selenium-standalone action [options]
```

It should install and then I should be able to start it.

Answer (score 1):

You mention having Java installed, but you didn't mention whether Java was in your `PATH` environment variable. Add a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and then add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

As It is clearly showing the usage error `Usage: selenium-standalone action [options]`
chances are that, you might be not passing any arguments after `selenium-standalone` command. Or a newLine/linebreak is being passed

Try giving or type the following in one go and then press enter

```
./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install
```

It should work fine.

Refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone for more info

Answer (score 0):

Just installing java worked for me.
Run in the terminal this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install default-jre
```

then run again

```
selenium-standalone install && selenium-standalone start
```